# Query String URL to Clean URL using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

If any one can help me? I am in big trouble due to lack of .htaccess mod-rewrite knowledge.

I have a query string url as below

```
http://10.101.101.56/project/index.php?id=add_project&un=ravi80
```

I need to convert this url in to clean url like below

```
http://10.101.101.46/project/add_project/ravi80
```

All urls are redirected through index.php file only.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^add-project/(.*)$ index.php?id=add_project&un=$1 [NC,L]
```